# Java/LWJGL 3 Optimization and Render error

Tags: opengl, java, rendering, lwjgl, lwjgl3

(I asked the same question on StackOverflow but didn't got an answer. It's the first time I post here so idk if this is not allowed or anything, so if it is please tell me)

I was following ThinMatrix's tutorial on OPENGL/LWJGL 3 3D Game Tutorial series [(here)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP), even though my code was wrote a little different from his, it was going well.

I could render an object like the image below using basic LWJGL 3 methods for rendering/shading. Basically, using this method in the **Render** class:

```
 //Old method
    
    public void createModel(EntityLoader entity, StaticShader shader) {
        
        ModelLoader model = entity.getModel();
        MeshLoader mesh = model.createModel();
        glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoId());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        shader.setUniformFloat("shineDamper", model.getShineDamper());
        shader.setUniformFloat("reflectivity", model.getReflectivity());
        
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransfMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), 
                entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.setUniformMatrix("transformationMatrix", transformationMatrix);
        
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture());
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), "texture"), 0); 

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        
        mesh.cleanUp();
    }
```

And calling it out in the **main** class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Render render = new Render();
        window = render.init();
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        
        createCapabilities(); 
        Light light = new Light(new Vector3f(0,0,20), new Vector3f(1,1,1));
        
        ObjLoader obj = new ObjLoader();
        ModelLoader squareModel = obj.loadObj("game_engine/src/Objetos/Ico.obj");
        EntityLoader squareEntity = new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,0,-5),0,0,0,1);
        
        squareModel.setShineDamper(10);
        squareModel.setReflectivity(1);
        squareModel.loadTexture("game_engine/src/Texturas/awesomeface.png");
        
        Camera camera = new Camera();
        
        StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();
        shader.start();
        shader.use();
        
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            render.prepare();
            processInput(window);
            
            glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, resizeWindow);
            GLFW.glfwSetScrollCallback(window, new GLFWScrollCallback() {
                @Override public void invoke (long win, double dx, double dy) {
                    XScroll = (float) dx;
                    YScroll = (float) dy;
                }
            });
            
            camera.move(window, YScroll);
            YScroll = 0;
            
            shader.setUniformVector("lightPosition", light.getPosition());
            shader.setUniformVector("lightColour", light.getColour());
        
            Matrix4f viewMatrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
            shader.setUniformMatrix("viewMatrix", viewMatrix);
        
            shader.setUniformMatrix("projectionMatrix", render.getProjectionMatrix());
            
            render.createModel(squareEntity, shader);
            
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();    
        }
        shader.cleanup();
        glfwTerminate();

    }
```

[image]

Until the 13 video, Optimizing, where he teached how to do the same procedure in a more optimized way, using HashMaps and ArrayLists to store the entities and calling the VAO elements only once per list of entities.
So, I made this **MasterRender** class:

```
public class Master {
    
    private StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();
    private Render renderer = new Render(shader);
    
    private Map<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>> entities = new HashMap<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>>();
    
    public void render(Light sun, Camera camera){
        renderer.prepare();
        shader.start();
        shader.use();
        
        shader.setUniformVector("lightPosition", sun.getPosition());
        shader.setUniformVector("lightColour", sun.getColour());
        
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
        shader.setUniformMatrix("viewMatrix", viewMatrix);
        
        shader.setUniformMatrix("projectionMatrix", renderer.getProjectionMatrix());
    }
    
    public void processEntity(EntityLoader entity) {
        ModelLoader entityModel = entity.getModel();
        List<EntityLoader> batch = entities.get(entityModel);
        if(batch!=null) {
            batch.add(entity);
        }else {
            List<EntityLoader> newBatch = new ArrayList<EntityLoader>();
            newBatch.add(entity);
            entities.put(entityModel, newBatch);
        }
    }
    
    public void renderEntity() {
        
        renderer.render(entities);
        
        shader.stop();
        entities.clear();
    }
    
    public long loadWindow() {
        return renderer.init();
    }
    
    public void cleanup() {
        shader.cleanup();
    }

}
```

And used new methods in the Render class:

```
//Optimized methods
    
    public void render(Map<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>> entities) {
        for(ModelLoader model:entities.keySet()) {
            prepareModel(model);
            List<EntityLoader> batch = entities.get(model);
            for(EntityLoader entity : batch) {
                prepareEntity(entity);
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.createModel().getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            }
            unbindModel();
        }
        
    }
    
    private void prepareModel(ModelLoader model) {
        MeshLoader mesh = model.createModel();
        glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoId());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        shader.setUniformFloat("shineDamper", model.getShineDamper());
        shader.setUniformFloat("reflectivity", model.getReflectivity());
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture());
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), "texture"), 0); 
        
    }
    
    private void unbindModel() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    }
    
    private void prepareEntity(EntityLoader entity) {
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransfMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), 
                entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.setUniformMatrix("transformationMatrix", transformationMatrix);
        
    }
```

Finally, I adjusted the **main** class, much like he did in the video

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Master render = new Master();
        window = render.loadWindow();
...
List<EntityLoader> allIcos = new ArrayList<EntityLoader>();
        allIcos.add(new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,0,-5),0,0,0,1));
        
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            processInput(window);
            
            glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, resizeWindow);
            GLFW.glfwSetScrollCallback(window, new GLFWScrollCallback() {
                @Override public void invoke (long win, double dx, double dy) {
                    XScroll = (float) dx;
                    YScroll = (float) dy;
                }
            });
            
            camera.move(window, YScroll);
            YScroll = 0;

            render.render(light, camera);
            for(EntityLoader Ico : allIcos) {
                render.processEntity(Ico);
                Ico.changeRot(0, 3, 0);
            }
            render.renderEntity();
            
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();    
        }
```

Not only it didn't work, it bought up a log error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8b8cd07b0, pid=11800, tid=7260
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (16.0.2+7) (build 16.0.2+7-67)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.dll+0x8507b0]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages br.com.renanlima.git.main

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001ae5e0ce780):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7260, stack(0x0000007d29000000,0x0000007d29100000)]

Stack: [0x0000007d29000000,0x0000007d29100000],  sp=0x0000007d290ff350,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvoglv64.dll+0x8507b0]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.nglDrawElements(IIIJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4
j  br.com.renanlima.render.Render.render(Ljava/util/Map;)V+84
j  br.com.renanlima.render.Master.renderEntity()V+8
j  br.com.renanlima.git.main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+254
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000
...
```

My question is: What did I do wrong in this new method of rendering? I looked up other tutorials besides ThinMatrix's one and they seen to all do it in a similar way.

**EDIT 1:** So, using Eclipse's debugger I found out 2 things:
1 - For some reason, the "transformationMatrix" is loading different, even though the two methods are the same and the parameters they are getting are the same.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhCBk.png) are the matrix variables using the "createModel()" method, the one that works

[And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQKjh.png) are the matrix variables using the optimized method, the one that doesn't work

This seems to be the only matrix/vertex in which this happens, but I could be overlooking something

2 - I think I've pinpointed the specific part where the crash happens.
When running the "glDrawElements" method.

[image]

More especificaly, on this part of the method:

[image]

But none of the variables seem to be wrong before that method is called. Again, I could be overlooking something, but there are a sh*tton of variables at the "findNative()" part, so I will look better into it.

**EDIT 1.2:** I solved the transformationMatrix error. It was because of the  "changeRot(0, 3, 0);" being called early. But I still can't find out why the crash at "glDrawElements" happens. Can someone please help me with this? If the question is confusing, please tell me so I can try to explain it better.

Comment: Surely you've already checked your favorite debugger? What does it say?

Comment: I put an edit with the debugging process, using Eclipse's debugger.